# Are there automated proof search algorithms for extended Frege systems?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, computational-complexity, proof-theory

Nowadays standard in automated theorem proofs are algorithms based on resolution system. There were quite a few attempts to present algorithms based on natural deduction (which is stronger than resolution), however, it turned out that such algorithms were less efficient than resolution-based ones.

On the other hand, extended Frege systems are at least as strong as Frege systems (and hence natural deduction) and can possibly be even super-polynomially stronger. Hence, the question: are (were) there any attempts to create an algorithm for proof search in extended Frege systems or natural deduction augmented with extension rule?